# C Elapsed time linux

Tags: c, linux

Sorry I am new to C. But what am I doing wrong? Tried almost everything, but still can not calculate seconds passed to execute the code between t1 and t2, always returns me 
Finished in 0.00 seconds.
Thanks for your patience :)

```
#include <time.h>

clock_t t1, t2;

t1 = clock();
sleep(5);
t2 = clock();
printf("\nFinished in %.2f seconds.\n\n", (t2-t1)*1.0/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If coarse granularity (whole second) is ok, perhaps `time(2)` and `time_t` are good enough.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static time_t t1, t2;

int
main(void)
{
  t1 = time(0);
  (void) sleep(5);
  t2 = time(0);

  (void) printf("\nFinished in %d seconds.\n\n", (int) (t2-t1));

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Works great, thanks! Btw. one question: why do you add (void) in front of sleep and printf?

Comment: Both `sleep(3)` and `printf(3)` return values, which this example program will not process. Out of long habit, I cast to (void) return values my code will ignore, but I rarely see this level of fussiness in others' programs, and my style likely doesn't match current practice (or idioms). You might read the documentation for those functions, and consider when a long-running or critically important application might actually need to check their return values.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `clock_t` does not take input account the "wall time", but CPU time.
The CPU is not effectively executing the code when it sleeps for 5 seconds.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, what should I use instead? My plan is to calculate network transfer speed, I am able to count packets in/out but I need some timer to calculate it per second, but I am not sure what to use instead of clock_t.

Comment: `gettimeofday()` -- resolution is microseconds.

Answer (score 0):

`clock()` is unsuitable for measuring elapsed time. It's resolution is generally very low and it only measures CPU time, not wall time. If you're targeting Unix you should use `clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, ...)`. On Windows `QueryPerformanceCounter()` is the API to use.

It is worth noting that `gettimeofday()` is also unsuitable because it is affected by leap seconds and adjustments by the network time protocol.